# Codeforces "The New President "

Tags: c++

I tried to answer write a code to solve [this](http://codeforces.com/gym/100155/problem/A) problem, but I'm still getting a wrong answer at test 15 and I don't know what is missing in my code.
I tried a lot of test cases but the code has solved them all correctly.

My Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c; cin >> c;
    int v; cin >> v;

    if (c == 1 && v == 0)
    {
        cout << 1 << " " << 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        int cArray[c + 1];

        int voting[v][c];
        for (int j = 0; j<v; j++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z<c; z++)
            {
                int temp; cin >> temp;
                voting[j][z] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= c; j++)cArray[j] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j<v; j++)cArray[voting[j][0]]++;

        int maxim = 0;
        int maxN = 0;
        int count = 0;
        map<int, int > cand;
        for (int j = 1; j <= c; j++)
        {
            if (cArray[j]>maxN)
            {
                cand.clear();
                cand[j] = 1;
                maxN = cArray[j];
                maxim = j;
                count = 0;
            }
            else if (cArray[j] == maxN)
            {
                cand[j] = 1;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 0)
            cout << maxim << " " << 1;

        else 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<v; j++)
            {
                for (int z = 1; z<c; z++) 
                {
                    if (cand.count(voting[j][z])) 
                    {
                        cArray[voting[j][z]]++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            maxim = 0;
            maxN = 0;
            count = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= c; j++)
            {
                if (cArray[j]>maxN)
                {
                    maxN = cArray[j];
                    maxim = j;
                    count = 0;
                }
                else if (cArray[j] == maxN)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            cout << maxim << " " << 2;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting that you're allowed to get that far with Variable Length Arrays in play. Looks like Codeforce is using a compiler with some non-standard extensions.

Comment: Don't have any improvement suggestions for you, but your algorithm is almost pure brute force, and usually these competition problems require some trick to get the answer in under the time requirement when given a worst-case input.

Comment: yes, you are totally right but in this problem the worst case is nothing so I solved it with the first way came to my mind .. But i'm still getting wrong answer not time limit exceed :(

Comment: Because number of voters is limited by 100, but number of candidates not, brute force works perfect. First run check two winners and second run check, who is better.
If number of voters would be unlimited, and number of candidates *small* (limited up to 2000), best algo would be to run once and fill table C * C, comparing each candidate to each other, and parallel to that find two best of them. Then after checking two best of them, we will know who wins, according to that table.

Comment: If you wanted a test case: [this](https://ideone.com/FKQJ1P) input results in `1 1` when the correct answer is `2 2`.

Comment: how is the correct answer 2 2 ?? 3 voters have voted to the candidate number 1 in the first round

Comment: @oyass Three out of seven did. Unless over half voted for the leading candidate, it proceeds to round 2. `3/7 < 1/2`, so in the second round it narrows to `1` and `2`. They get `3` and `4` votes respectively, and thus `2` is the winner in the second round.

Comment: yes you are right I have just noticed it now !! must be larger than 50 %

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm for checking the first round (win or top two candidates) seems wrong. It looks like you are expecting the top two candidates to have the same number of primary votes - this is not the case. You want to pick the top two candidates and the top one wins if it has more than 50 % of the vote.

I don't want to give you the answer (as that is the point of doing the exercises), but you need to rethink how you are processing the first part of the vote.

Also note that once someone has voted for one of the top two candidates, their secondary votes should not then count toward the other candidate (which you are currently doing).

Comment: you are right and I have improved it but it still wrong answer but at test 35